# jquery child element as trigger

Tags: jquery

When "forum-title" is clicked, I want "subtopic-frame" within the parent "forum-topics-head" to expand. There are multiple "forum-topics-head" (with all associated children) on this page.

The way I have it now, the "forum-topics-head" is the trigger, but I want the "forum-title" to be the trigger.

html:

```
<div class="forum-topic-head">
    <div class="forum-title">Forum Title</div>
    <div class="subtopic-frame">
        subtopic 1
        subtopic 2
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".forum-topic-head").click(function(){
        $(this).children(".subtopic-frame").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).children(".expand").delay("200").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: what about showing the way you have it now

Comment: doh...forgot to paste it there. Update to show current jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".forum-title").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".subtopic-frame").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).siblings(".expand").delay("200").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this`, `.closest()` and `.find()` to operate only within the currently clicked section.  For example:

```
$(".forum-title").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".forum-topic-head").find(".subtopic-frame").slideToggle("slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tkcRa/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.forum-title').on('click',function(){
        $(this).parent('.forum-topic-head').children('.subtopic-frame').slideToggle();
    });
});
```